# XQuery - How can I count and save informations in a map

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to safe IDs in a map. If the ID occurs again, I want to set the count ($value) from 1 to 2 and so on.
Following you find my code:

```css
declare namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com";
declare variable $idMap := map{};

declare function functx:uniqueID ($entityID as xs:string) as xs:integer {
let $idMap := map:merge(($idMap, if(not(map:contains($idMap, $entityID))) then map:entry($entityID, 1) else map:entry(entityID, map:get($idMap, $entityID)+1)))
return map:get($idMap, $entityID)
};

declare variable $map := map:merge((
 map:entry("Sheff", "85246525"),
 map:entry("Peter", "85246454"),
 map:entry("Marcel", "85246525"),
 map:entry("Lion", "85244565"),
 map:entry("Klaus", "85241234")
));


map:for-each($map,
  function($key, $value) {
    functx:uniqueID($value)
  } 
)
```

Result:

```css
1
1
1
1
1
```

Expected Result

```css
1
1
2      (: Because it is the second time, that 85246525 occurs. :)
1
1
```

Edited 23.03.2020 - 17:45: 
I have a complex xquery, which functions. But the target system need unique IDs per line. I have a map, which hold my information like the upper one. I need to add something behind the IDs like (001, 002, 003) to have different IDs.

Best practice would be, that only douplicate IDs get a added number.

Do you understand or what do you need more from me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to construct a new map with an "index" added to duplicated values is to use grouping:

```
map:merge(
    for $key in map:keys($map)
    group by $value := $map($key)
    for $group-key at $pos in $key
    return map:entry($group-key, $value || '-' || format-integer($pos, '000'))
)
```

At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgeT that gives

```
{
    "Peter": "85246454-001",
    "Marcel": "85246525-001",
    "Sheff": "85246525-002",
    "Lion": "85244565-001",
    "Klaus": "85241234-001"
  }
```

Comment: After long time experementing with your code suggestion, I got the expected result. Very thanks to all of you, for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've written your code as if `$idMap` is mutable, and as if calling `functx:uniqueID()` has the side-effect of modifying the map. That isn't going to work in a functional language.

You need a completely different approach; and to help you with that, we need to look at the problem you are trying to solve, not at your existing approach to a solution.

Comment: Yes, I am really new in functional programming. Normally I program in Java. Thats a complete other (hello) world for me. :D

Comment: Try to avoid procedural language when describing the problem "I need to add something". Use functional language instead: "each X in the result needs to have an ID satisfying the following constraints...". Functional programming starts with the description of requirements.